# Interface Builder Off Vertically

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xcode4

I'm using Xcode 4.0 and when building my view in Interface Builder everything looks great. When I run my app with the simulator or iOS device the whole view is off vertically (showing a white bar at bottom). It looks to be off by 20 pixels. TabBar, Labels, Tableview, Text and background image are all shifted up. Any ides? Thanks

Comment: 20 pixels is the size of the status bar. Do you have it hidden in the app but not IB?

Comment: When running the app the status bar is still there. ????

Answer (score 1):

Are you running fullscreen? I'm guessing that you've set the Status Bar to 'None' which means the size of your view in the Interface Builder is wrong.

In your *ViewController.xib when you set the Status Bar to 'None' it sets the height of the view to be 460, when it should be 480.

Comment: Yes running full screen and the status bar is set to Gray. But your right it's like it thinks I have said None to status bar and so it shifted everything up.