# iphone ipad xib not loading perfectly

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, xib

I have two xib files created separately for iphone and ipad in the universal application.
xib file design is good, but it when it load, white gap is their at the bottom side .

my iphone xib also loading like this only....

How to rectify this anyone help me,,,,

Thanks in advance,
Suresh.M

Comment: Possibly same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409163/interface-builder-off-vertically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check it with two lines of code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        NSLog(@"Call your iPad xib file");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Call your iPhone xib file");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you check all the Layout Settings ? 
Because that's one problem i had very often.

Answer (score 0):

change the position of uiview(i.e. x,y positions)  , in your viewwillappear or viewdidload method.Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Sounds obvious but check the dimensions of your views. This has happened to me before when the xib has been simulating the status bar and I have then turned the status bar off. The resulting dimensions end up 20 pixels short.